# How to modify environment variable with Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have defined environment variables like this:

```
environment {
    RELEASE_NAME = "${BRANCH_NAME}"
}
```

Now I would like to do something like:

```
environment {
    RELEASE_NAME = "${BRANCH_NAME}".replaceAll("/", "-")
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables need to be a string, or need to be able to be coerced to a string. The way I prefer to do something like this is with a GString.

```
environment {
    RELEASE_NAME = "${BRANCH_NAME.replaceAll('/', '-')}"
}
```

Put everything you want to do in the `${}` This assumes that BRANCH_NAME is a valid variable pointing to an object that has a replaceAll method.

Comment: How to do this when the replacement string is the value of another variable?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
environment {
    BRANCH = "${BRANCH_NAME}"
    RELEASE_NAME = ${BRANCH}.replaceAll("/", "-")  
}
```